# Soultion of trigonometric equation

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, vectors

Let $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\theta>0$. Define $f(k,\theta)\triangleq \big [\cos k\theta~~~\sin k\theta \big]$. Then, it follows from direct calculation that
\begin{align}
f(k,\theta)-2\cos\theta f(k-1,\theta)+f(k-2,\theta)=0.
\end{align}
How can I prove or disprove by counter-example the following:

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, 
\begin{align}
f(k,\theta)a-2\cos\theta f(k-1,\theta)b+f(k-2,\theta)c=0,\qquad {\rm for~all~} k\in\mathbb{Z},
\end{align}
if and only if $a=b=c$.

Comment: I can't think of any counter-example. I think I should be able to prove this, but don't know how to show it rigorously.